# Why doesn't Autowiring work for this Spring MVC String bean property?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, autowired

```
@Autowired
private String defaultLanguage;
```

When I try to `@Autowire` the `defaultLanguage` field of the `CountryBean` class as follows:

```
<beans:bean id="countryBean" class="geoapp.CountryBean">
    <beans:property name="defaultLanguage" value="English" />
</beans:bean>
```

I get this error:

```
Error creating bean with name 'CountryBean': 
Injection of autowired dependencies failed; 
nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Could not autowire field: 
private java.lang.String geoapp.CountryBean.defaultLanguage; 
nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: 
No matching bean of type [java.lang.String] found for dependency:
expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for 
this dependency. 
Dependency annotations:
{@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}:
```

When it says `No matching bean of type [java.lang.String] found for dependency`, I wonder if there's something else I need to say to let it know that the value `English` is a `String`?

Answer (score 2):

Since you are explicitly specifying the property value via xml, there is no need to have the AutoWired annotation.

Answer (score 1):

You are not using the autowire feature properly.
You can either:

- Use the `<beans:property ... />` in the XML and add a setter for the property in the class
- Use the `@Autowired` annotation that automatically looks in the Spring context for an existing bean that has your property **class** (in your case, `String`)

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are correct, but to clarify things, those beans defined in the *.xml files are processed before any @ type annotations get processed.  So for your example, the bean "CountryBean" is processed before the property "defaultLanguage" is processed, leaving the dependency null.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another 'the other answers are correct', but here's another tidbit for you -- Spring will automatically set enums for you, so if you had an enum of languages and your bean definition had something like ", you'd get a type safe enum in there, instead of a String.

Answer (score 0):

If you want autowiring your property, you need to make a new bean for that defaultLanguage String. Then equate the bean's name and field's name.